# push notifications using mixpanel. After selecting groups of 50K+ users, we see around 100 messages received and 0 messages opened.

Tags: unity-game-engine, push-notification, mixpanel

We want to send push notifications using mixpanel.
After selecting groups of 50K+ users, we see around 100 messages received and 0 messages opened. Any ideas as to technical issues that might be causing these severely dysfunctional funnels.

Also I am not able to locate my own device to run a test.  I have confirmed that many of our users have a "tokenValue" set.  Our app is written in Unity.

Comment: Hi @user9371310, and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Are you getting any errors?  Can you share a snippet of relevant code?  What have you tried so far to fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: This question does not appear to be on topic for Stack Overflow.